# Using export template to work around issues in renaming / moving resources?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

Working on a project that was started by some outside developers.

They did not follow our Azure governance document, partly because we had not developed it yet.

So now we have 100 or so resources that
•   Don't follow our naming convention
•   Are in the wrong resource groups
•   Are in the wrong region
or all of the above.

We have created a "desired state", i.e. so that for every resource we have what it should be named, the RG it is should be in, the region it should be in, etc.

However, for most resources you are not able to change many of these attributes. Bummer.

I think we can just export each resource as a template, manually change the few attributes that need to be different (see above) and then create a “new” resource based on this template.

Any gotchas? Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes and no. some of the resources are not exportable to the said template, for some - some properties might not get exported. So you'd have to be very careful when doing this.

Your data **will** be lost if you do this (so it wont just rename\move those resource, it will create new ones). This may be a show stopper.

Also, exported templates are extremely low quality, I'd probably just develop a new template with whatever you need from scratch.

Comment: I am glad that you pointed all of this out to me. I will have to take this into account for sure. Why in the world would MS have an export to template function for which some properties don't get exported! My goodness. Many of the most important resources are web code from Visual Studio so I think it might be best just to create those directly. For others we will have to compare old resources to new resources very carefully. Any other suggestions on the best way to do this?

Comment: well, most of the properties will be exported, but some might be lost. its not like they WILL be lost, but some things might be lost, so you have to check the templates you export. I usually go with resources.azure.com. its a very nice way to get current resource state, if that won't show you something, there is probably no way to retrieve it